# Black Screen on simple Python & Kivy app

Tags: python, windows, oop, kivy

I'm a newbie in Python language and I'm also starting to use Kivy library. I have a Windows 8 OS and I wrote this first code to make an example:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleApp().run()
```

But after running, the output was this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqGMa.png)

There is a black blank window less "Hello World", so I cannot understand the source of the problem because it seems very strange.

Comment: Having the exact same issue except on Linux. Just loads a black box. Have you found any resolution to this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Since your code works (for me...)
I would suggest that you download the latest kivy
[installation-windows](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)

And try again.